# Java collection lookup by a key, sort by a value

Tags: java, collections

I have a structure in java with a string key and a float score.   I want to store these in a collection where I can do a simple lookup by the key,  or a "pop" the item with the lowest score.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need two collections / data structures.
I'd suggest using a custom Object:

```
public class GiveMeANamePlease implements Comparable<GiveMeANamePlease>{
    private final String key;
    private final float score;
    // add constructor, getter, compareTo, equals and hashcode
}
```

You could use a `HashMap<String, GiveMeANamePlease>` to do the lookup by key, and a `TreeSet<GiveMeANamePlease>` to sort by score.

You can pop the lowest element in your TreeSet like this:

```
treeSet.remove(treeSet.first());
```

which is not that great because it requires a double lookup (inefficient and not thread safe).

**Hint:** If you only want to pop the minimum, it would be more efficient to store the score in a [Min-Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), but there's no standard Java implementation for that.

Answer (score 1):

Make your structure implement Comparable based on your score, and use a map for storing the instances by key, and a SortedSet to keep the instances ordered by score.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single Collection type with that runctionality in my knoweledge.

For storing I would use a Map. For the lowest/highest score, I would get the EntrySet of the map and use that to create a second Collection which sorts the entries by value.